# How to add NavigationView Menu dynamically?

Tags: android, kotlin

So, I would like add menu items to navigationView. The idea is that, there are Projects, and every project belongs to a group. So the group count can be from 1 to N.

These groups are stored in Room database, thease groups don't change at run time, so it is not necessary to invalidate/reset navigation view.

I created a main fragment whic is called Projects, when the user clicks the generated project group menu items, I would like to navigate to the Projects fragment, but with different projectGroupId because of the filtering.

Althought I found the solution for creating menu items, but I don't know how to handle the click event, and how to highlight the menu item like a standard static menu item.

```
Main Activity navigation view
    private fun setUpNavigation() {
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main)
        setSupportActionBar(binding.appBarMain.toolbar)

        val menuItems = mutableListOf(
            R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_calendar, R.id.nav_project_browser
        )

        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            menuItems.toSet(),
            binding.drawerLayout
        )

        setCounterValueToMenuItem(binding.navView.menu.findItem(R.id.nav_home),2)

        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        binding.navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }

Generate menu method
rivate fun addExtraMenu(){
        val navView = binding.navView
        val menu = navView.menu
        val subMenu = menu.addSubMenu("Custom menus")

        subMenu.add(0,0,0,"Menu 1",)
        setMenuItemActionView(subMenu[0])

        subMenu.add(0,1,0,"Menu2")

        subMenu[0].setOnMenuItemClickListener {
            it.isChecked = true

            return@setOnMenuItemClickListener true
        }

        setCounterValueToMenuItem(subMenu.getItem(0),2)
    }

    private fun setMenuItemActionView(menuItem: MenuItem){
        menuItem.setActionView(R.layout.drawer_menu_with_counter)
    }

    private fun setCounterValueToMenuItem(menuItem: MenuItem,count: Int){
        val frameLayout: FrameLayout = menuItem.actionView as FrameLayout
        val textView = frameLayout.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.counter)

        textView.text = count.toString()
    }
```

Comment: I only understood the question. Use `navigationView.inflateMenu(menu)` to add the menu dynamically.

Comment: We can say that, the menu items come from database, because of this, I can not create another menu resource file, because it has static menu items. As you can se in the code, I create a menu group, add as many menu items to the menu group as I want, and after that, I add this group to the navView. But in this case, the navComponent not handle the menu click.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but I think maybe the easiest solution would be to create your navigation destinations and menu of destinations in XML and swap out/show/hide/rename the associated Menu items and destinations based on what your dynamic projects are. Then you can continue to use the NavController in the usual way, and you don't have to try to duplicate NavigationView icon/label animations and have them match the default behavior for Navigation destinations.

Comment: Tanks, but unfortunatelly I can't create static menu items, because I don't know exactly how menu menuItems there will be. If I understand correcyly what did you say, in your solutuion I should have to know the number of items .

Answer (score 0):

So finally I figured out how to handle this situation.

In the menu items observer (in fact, these items are just a String name list), I call addExtraMenu function. The first menu item index starts from 0...N, therefore the submenu index has to be a big number, so that by chance it should not be the same. If the menuItems changed in runtime, you have to remove the old subMenu, and recreate it. I didn't want to handle the checked state, it wasn't necessary in my case.

```
 private fun addExtraMenu(types: List<IndustryType>) {
        val navView = binding.navView
        val menu = navView.menu
        val subMenuIndex = 999

        menu.findItem(subMenuIndex)?.let {
            menu.removeItem(it.itemId)
        }

        val subMenu = menu.addSubMenu(0, subMenuIndex, 0, R.string.drawer_menu_dynamic_group_label)

        types.forEachIndexed { _, industryType ->

            subMenu.add(0, industryType.indexOfMenu, industryType.indexOfMenu, industryType.name)

            setMenuItemActionView(subMenu[industryType.indexOfMenu])

            subMenu.getItem(industryType.indexOfMenu)?.setOnMenuItemClickListener {
                setDynamicMenuClickListener(industryType.oid)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun setDynamicMenuClickListener(industryTypeOid: String?): Boolean {
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main)

        binding.drawerLayout.close()

        val b = bundleOf(Pair("industryTypeOid", industryTypeOid))

        navController.navigate(R.id.nav_project_browser, b)

        return true
    }
```